# Sacar datos de una consulta en PHP

Tags: php, array

tengo la siguiente funcion para hacer consultas a la base de datos:

```
 function consultar_calendarios($conexion, $oidu, $nombre)
    {
        $consulta = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS TOTAL FROM CALENDARIOS WHERE NOMBRE=:nombre AND OID_U=:odiu";
        $stmt = $conexion->prepare($consulta);
        $stmt->bindParam(':oidu', $oidu);
        $stmt->bindParam(':nombre', $nombre);
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->fetchColumn();
```

y ahora quiero sacar de esa consulta las variables que me devuelve (oidu y nombre) en un array. Soy muy novato, apenas hace dos días que he empezado a programar.

Un saludo y gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola, quieres que te retorne el resultado de la consulta en ves de el total?

Comment: Esa consulta no te devuelve ninguna de las variables mencionadas, lo único que te regresará por ejemplo es `Total: 12` siendo 12 un número de ejemplo pues estas indicando que haga un conteo. Las variables `nombre` y `odiu` ahí están siendo trabajadas como valores para condicionar que registros debe contabilizar tu consulta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Esa consulta no te devuelve ninguna de las variables mencionadas, lo único que te regresará por ejemplo es `Total: 12` siendo 12 un número de ejemplo pues estas indicando que haga un conteo. Las variables `nombre` y `odiu` ahí están siendo trabajadas como valores para condicionar que registros debe contabilizar tu consulta.

Si deseas mandar dichas variables por medio de la estructura de un *array* entonces debes hacerlo del modo siguiente dentro de la función `consultar_calendarios`

```
$datos = array("nombre" => $nombre, "odiu" => $odiu);
```

Para que después puedas obtener sus valores de este modo:

```
echo $datos["nombre"];
```

y

```
echo $datos["odiu"];
```

O en una sola instrucción a través de un bucle *foreach*

```
foreach($datos as $dato){
    echo $dato;
}
```

Ahora que si quieres que esos valores de `nombre` y `odiu` salgan al momento de ejecutar tu consulta; deberás escribirla de este modo

```
"SELECT nombre, odiu, COUNT(*) AS TOTAL FROM CALENDARIOS WHERE NOMBRE=:nombre AND OID_U=:odiu
  GROUP BY nombre, odiu"
```

Comment: El ultimo consejo, donde indicas la consulta, donde agregas `nombre`, `odiu` y ademas el `count` dará error, ya que deberas hacer un group by al final de la consulta por las columnas `nombre` y `odiu`

Comment: Cierto se me pasó deja corrijo